# What are those extra curly brackets doing in C#?

Tags: c#

I have no idea how to search for this question; forgive me if it's redundant.

So, I have some code like this:

```
textBox1.InputScope = new InputScope { Names = { _Scope } };
```

The Names property is of type IList

Is my code adding an item to a list or creating a new list?

**What's that extra curly bracket doing?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a [*collection initializer*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx), but one which isn't creating a new collection - it's just adding to an existing one. It's used as the *initializer-value* part of a *member-initializer* within an *object-initializer*. It's the equivalent of:

```
InputScope tmp = new InputScope();
tmp.Names.Add(_Scope);
textBox1.InputScope = tmp;
```

See section 7.6.10.3 of the C# 4 spec for more infomation.

Comment: Is that like the double braces trick in Java minus the horrifying implications of an anonymous class?

Comment: @G_H: Somewhat... it's easier to talk about it just in terms of what it actually does in C# rather than how it can be poorly emulated in Java though :)

Comment: @Jon, why doesn't `var _List = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }; _List = { 4, 5, 6 };` work, then? Because it can only be done once?

Comment: @JerryNixon: Collection initializers can only appear as part of object creation expressions. You can still do `_List = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }` though.

Comment: @Jon, hopefully not too off-topic. Is there a add-more-than-one-at-a-time syntax for enumerables that would do something like that syntax up there? Something like _List.AddRange({ 4, 5, 6});? I *totally* get why that does not work. But anything like it?

Comment: @JerryNixon: No, I'm afraid not.

Comment: @JerryNixon: You could use `_list.AddRange(new[] { 4,5,6 });`.  This is probably a bit inefficient.

Answer (score 11):

This is a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).  It's allowing you to add items to the `Names` collection.

Answer (score 7):

```
new InputScope { // indicates an object-initializer for InputScope using
                 // the default constructor
   Names = { // indicates an in-place usage of a collection-initializer
     _Scope  // adds _Scope to Names
   } // ends the collection-initializer
}; // ends the object-initializer
```

i.e.

```
var tmp = new InputScope();
tmp.Names.Add(_Scope);
textBox1.InputScope = tmp;
```

Answer (score 2):

The first curly brace set is the object initializer. The second set is an [IList of names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscope.names%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (collection).

Comment: Edited to agree with documentation - both arrays and collections (ilist here) support object initialization in the same way. I assumed it was an array. Thanks for clarification!